# AngularJS : directive does not update scope after $http response in parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I got this directive:

```
.directive('studentTable', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            students: "=",
            collapsedTableRows: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/studentTable.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Template:

```
  <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><b>Name</b></th>
                <th><b>Surname</b></th>
                <th><b>Group</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="student in students track by $index">
                <td>{{ student.name }}</td> 
                <td>{{ student.surname }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.group }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Use directive in my html like this:

```
<div student-table students="students" 
    collapsedTableRows="collapsedTableRows"></div>
```

And the parent controller:

```
.controller('SchoolController', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User){
    $scope.students = [];
    $scope.collapsedTableRows = [];

    $scope.search = function(value) {
        if(value) {
            var orgId = $state.params.id;
            var search = User.searchByOrg(orgId, value);

            search.success(function (data) {
                $scope.students = data;
                $scope.collapsedTableRows = [];
                _(data).forEach(function () {
                    $scope.collapsedTableRows.push(true);
                });

            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Now at the beginnig, the table is empty, because no users in students array. After I click search, and get list of students object, I put them to scope variable, but the directive does not update, neither it find change in model (`scope.$watch('students',...`). What am I missing?

P.S. If I simulate the data using `$httpBackend`, directive works as it should.

Comment: Is your success method being called?

Comment: Yes, and console.log($scope.students) show array filled with objects after success in parent scope

Comment: Can you try instead of assigning `$scope.students=data;`, do a push of each item into the `students` array.

Comment: Nothing changed, after I populate the students array, directive does not notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that data object returning array of student because somtimes you have to use data.data that simple demo should helps you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UMHfzD4oSCv27PnD6Y6v?p=preview

```
 $http.get('studen.json').then(function(students) {

      $scope.students = students.data; //<-students.data here

    },
    function(msg) {
      console.log(msg)
    })
```

Comment: Ahhh, so ashamed of myself... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing the controller this way
    ...

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.students = data;
})
...
```

This will start a digest loop, if it's not already in progress. 
Another form that will do almost the same thing is this:

```
...
$scope.students = data;
$scope.$digest()
...
```

PS:
The first method is just a wrapper that execute a $rootScope.$digest() after evaluating the function, considering that a $digest evaluates the current scope and all it's children calling it on the $rootScope is pretty heavy.
So the second method should be preferred if it works.

Comment: Does the "students" array in the directive updates when the one in the controller is populated? This is the important information because in one case the problem is in the scope and in the other case the problem is the directive not updating the view.

Comment: Nope, I have scope.$watch('students', function(){..}, true) in directive link function, but it does not fire, except on directive initialization.